# Javaメソッドの始め方について

Tags: java

以下のようなコードを書き上げたのですが、どのメソッドのはじめIllegal start of expressionというエラーが表示されます。メソッドをPublic設定にしてみたり、Voidを変えてみたり試してみたのですが、原因がわかりません。解説お願いします。

```
class Assignment2_1 {

    public static void println(int[] seq) {
        System.out.println(seq[0]+" "+seq[1]+"\n");
    }

    static void swap(int[] seq) {
        int temp = seq[0];
        seq[0] = seq[1];
        seq[1] =  temp;


    public static  int[] copy(int[] seq) {
        int n = seq.length;
        int[] result  = new int[n];
        for(int i= 0; i<n;i++)
        result[i] = seq[i];
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

閉じ括弧が足りていないせいです。

```
class Assignment2_1 {
  public static void println(int[] seq) {
    System.out.println(seq[0]+" "+seq[1]+"\n");
  }

  static void swap(int[] seq) {
    int temp = seq[0];
    seq[0] = seq[1];
    seq[1] =  temp;
  } // ここ

  public static  int[] copy(int[] seq) {
    int n = seq.length;
    int[] result  = new int[n];
    for(int i= 0; i<n;i++)
    result[i] = seq[i];
    return result;
  }
} // ここ
```

と閉じ括弧を補えば、コンパイルは通ります。